# Extremely simple image-viewing program throwing "pyimage1 does not exist" exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm just trying to make a program to click on an image and view it in fullscreen. I am using Visual Studio 2022. My environment is Python 3.9 (64-bit). Pillow (9.4.0) is installed in the environment. I am on Windows 11. Here is the entirety of the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os

def main():
    image_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select Image")
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg="black")
    canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    pil_image = Image.open(image_path)
    pil_image = pil_image.resize((root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()), Image.LANCZOS)
    tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)
    canvas.create_image(root.winfo_screenwidth() // 2, root.winfo_screenheight() // 2, image=tk_image)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This code throws an `image "pyimage1" doesn't exist` exception after I run it and select an image. What could I possibly be doing wrong?

Comment: In which line does this code throw that error?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing it's because you call `filedialog.askopenfilename` before creating the root window. Because of that, tkinter will automatically create a root window for you. You then create a second root window, but the image you create by default is owned by the original root window. Therefore, the root window you created has no knowledge of the image.

You either need to create your root window before creating the `askopenfilename` method, or create your image as a child of the root window. The following example shows the latter:

```
tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image, master=root)
```